# MERGE statement updates even if the data is not updated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have a merge statement in which I'd like to update my table rows in case any of the columns have a different value. But it seems like even though most of the rows in the source table have remained intact, the `MERGE` statement performs an `UPDATE` on at least counts what it does an `UPDATE`.

```
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(50));

MERGE MyTarget AS TARGET
USING MySource AS SOURCE
ON (SOURCE.customeridHash = TARGET.Id)
WHEN MATCHED AND (TARGET.IsCompany <> SOURCE.company
    OR TARGET.Gender <> SOURCE.gender
    OR TARGET.BirthDate <> CONVERT(DATE, SOURCE.dateofbirth)
    OR TARGET.ZipCode <> SOURCE.ZipCode
    OR TARGET.City <> SOURCE.City
    OR TARGET.WantsEmail <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.noemail = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OR TARGET.WantsSMS <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.nosms = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OR TARGET.WantsDM <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.nodirectmarketing = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OR TARGET.WantsTM <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.notelemarketing = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OR TARGET.HasEmail <> SOURCE.HasEmail
    OR TARGET.HasMobilePhoneNumber <> SOURCE.HasMobilePhoneNumber
    OR TARGET.HasPhoneNumber = SOURCE.HasPhoneNumber
    OR TARGET.Created <> SOURCE.Created
    OR TARGET.Updated <> SOURCE.changed)
THEN
UPDATE SET TARGET.IsCompany = SOURCE.company,
    TARGET.Gender = SOURCE.gender,
    TARGET.BirthDate = CONVERT(DATE, SOURCE.dateofbirth),
    TARGET.ZipCode = SOURCE.ZipCode,
    TARGET.City = SOURCE.City,
    TARGET.WantsEmail = (CASE WHEN SOURCE.noemail = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    TARGET.WantsSMS = (CASE WHEN SOURCE.nosms = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    TARGET.WantsDM = (CASE WHEN SOURCE.nodirectmarketing = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    TARGET.WantsTM = (CASE WHEN SOURCE.notelemarketing = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    TARGET.HasEmail = SOURCE.HasEmail,
    TARGET.HasMobilePhoneNumber = SOURCE.HasMobilePhoneNumber,
    TARGET.HasPhoneNumber = SOURCE.HasPhoneNumber,
    TARGET.Created = SOURCE.Created,
    TARGET.Updated = SOURCE.changed
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (
    Id, 
    IsCompany, 
    Gender, 
    BirthDate, 
    ZipCode, 
    City, 
    WantsEmail, 
    WantsSMS,
    WantsDM, 
    WantsTM, 
    HasEmail, 
    HasMobilePhoneNumber, 
    HasPhoneNumber, 
    Created, 
    Updated
)
VALUES (
    SOURCE.customeridHash,
    SOURCE.company,
    SOURCE.gender,
    CONVERT(DATE, SOURCE.dateofbirth),
    SOURCE.ZipCode,
    SOURCE.City,
    (CASE WHEN SOURCE.noemail = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    (CASE WHEN SOURCE.nosms = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    (CASE WHEN SOURCE.nodirectmarketing = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    (CASE WHEN SOURCE.notelemarketing = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SOURCE.HasEmail,
    SOURCE.HasMobilePhoneNumber,
    SOURCE.HasPhoneNumber,
    SOURCE.Created,
    SOURCE.changed
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;

SELECT Change, COUNT(*) CountPerChange
FROM @SummaryOfChanges
GROUP BY Change;
```

I do some bookkeeping at the end of the update (the final `SELECT`) and it seems like almost all the rows that are not new, were updated. Is this a common behavior or is there really a value amongst my `<>` comparison for `WHEN MATCHED AND...` that is updated?

**Update:** As suggested by one of the comments, I wrote the following test to check whether my conditions trigger an update or not:

```
-- TEST MERGE
select count(*) 
from MyTarget TARGET join MySource SOURCE on TARGET.Id=SOURCE.customeridHash
where TARGET.IsCompany <> SOURCE.company
    OR TARGET.Gender <> SOURCE.gender
    OR TARGET.BirthDate <> CONVERT(DATE, SOURCE.dateofbirth)
    OR TARGET.ZipCode <> SOURCE.ZipCode
    OR TARGET.City <> SOURCE.City
    OR TARGET.WantsEmail <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.noemail = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OR TARGET.WantsSMS <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.nosms = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OR TARGET.WantsDM <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.nodirectmarketing = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OR TARGET.WantsTM <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.notelemarketing = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OR TARGET.HasEmail <> SOURCE.HasEmail
    OR TARGET.HasMobilePhoneNumber <> SOURCE.HasMobilePhoneNumber
    OR TARGET.HasPhoneNumber = SOURCE.HasPhoneNumber
    OR TARGET.Created <> SOURCE.Created
    OR TARGET.Updated <> SOURCE.changed;
```

I realised that this query returns the same number of updates. So it is somehow more about the condition that the `MERGE` statement. But I wonder how they trigger updates.

Comment: Run this as `select` to test your conditions with `using->inner join`, `when matched and` -> `where`.

Comment: That's really hard to say given the fact we don't have any sample data and output.... One thing I've noticed is that you have conditions like `OR TARGET.WantsEmail <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.noemail = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. In such  a condition, if `source.noemail` is null you will get 0 as the result of the case expression - which is something that you might have not paid attention to.

Comment: Also, a must read: Aaron Bertrand's [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I did the `SELECT` test you suggested and I realised that I get the same number of updates there. So it is probably more about the condition and the merge.

Comment: @ZoharPeled regarding the `OR TARGET.WantsEmail <> (CASE WHEN SOURCE.noemail = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` condition, are you suggesting that this will trigger an update every time?

Comment: You should process NULL values in `<>` conditions, if the values can be NULL, because `NULL <> AnyValue = false`

Comment: @DenisRubashkin but neither of those values for which I do a case are ever `NULL`. But maybe I should consider them being `NULL` in the query?

Comment: I'm not suggesting this condition will return true every time, just that if `noemail` is null than the result of the case expression will be `0`. Denis's suggestion might be good in this case (but not always!) - it would mean that `null` and `0` would both return the same value from the case expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own mistake, in the conditions I write:

```
OR TARGET.HasPhoneNumber = SOURCE.HasPhoneNumber
```

Which almost always renders true!